# Put one box into another

Tags: html, css

I'm making a section of a web-page with the div operator. So I've got one big box with smooth edges and some content, but I'd like to create a button inside this box and I would like to use the div attribute again. How would I style this new button through CSS? Obviously I would override my old button if I'd simply change the div attributes in the CSS.

Here's the code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>-
   <header>-
       <title> Derps</title>-
       <link type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   </header>
<body>
<div>
    <h1> Derpsps</h1>
    <p>
        Random text for my website
    </p>
      <img src="picture1.jpg " class="left"height="300" />
      <img src="logo-thingymchee.png" class="right"height="100" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
div{
    height:800px;
    width: 1300px;
    border-color:#6495ED;
    background-color:#BCD2EE;
    border-width:2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Some code is needed that what you have tried?

Comment: I added the code.

I haven't really tried anything other than adding another div box and that obviously doesn't work.

Comment: your question is not clear. you are asking to the  people to do code for you..!

Comment: try something...get a problem...then re-ask! :)

Comment: You want to add another `div` element inside of your current `div` element, and style that element differently? *How* do you want it to be styled?

Comment: Nevermind. Solved this using sections.

Comment: Sections? As an addendum on my comment on my answer below: please also read about "Semantic HTML". A `<section>`, unlike a `<div>`, has special meaning in HTML. Since HTML tags are used to describe their content, it is important you keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that what you're trying to achieve is this:

```
<!-- this is your original box -->
<div class="container">
    <!-- this will be the button -->
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

By adding a class to the first div, you can assign a specific style to it.
You could now do this:

```
div.container {
    height:800px;
    width: 1300px;
    border-color:#6495ED;
    background-color:#BCD2EE;
    border-width:2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
div div {
    // Other style here
}
```

Or any other form of CSS.

I do recommend to use an HTML `<button>` instead of a `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the classes to do that.

Create another div with the class "button"

Style the div.button via CSS

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <h1> Derpsps</h1>
    <p>
        Random text for my website
    </p>
    <img src="picture1.jpg " class="left"height="300" />
    <img src="logo-thingymchee.png" class="right"height="100" />
    <div class="button">Button</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div
{
    height:800px;
    width: 1300px;
    border-color:#6495ED;
    background-color:#BCD2EE;
    border-width:2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
div.button
{
    border-color:#6495ED;
    background-color:#BCD2EE;
    border-width:2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```